# Handling Object Dependency

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, loose-coupling

Consider the following class

```
class User
{
    protected $password;

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
}
```

I want to apply bcrypt on password using `Zend\Crypt\Password\Bcrypt` in user object, since this creates a dependency i want to know how to correctly deal with this, i can think about several approaches to make this work, let me elaborate

**Approach 1** : Here we instantiate the class inside the method and apply required changes.

```
class User
{
    protected $password;

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $bcrypt = new Bcrypt();
        $this->password = $bcrypt->create($password);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function verifyPassword($password)
    {
        $bcrypt = new Bcrypt();
        return $bcrypt->verify($password, $this->getPassword());
    }
}
```

Towards my understanding this is not recommended approach since i see two problems here

1. Bcrypt() is instantiated twice
2. This makes User object tightly coupled with Bcrypt

I can solve problem-1 by instantiating Bcrypt() once in class constructor and use it whenever required, however this does not solve problem-2

**Approach 2 :** Move Bcrypt object out of user class and inject it while setting the password

```
class User
{
    protected $password;

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;    
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
}

// Init Bcrypt
$bcrypt = new Bcrypt;

// Instantiate user object and create a password
$user = new User;
$user->setPassword($bcrypt->create($password));

// Verify user password
if ($bcrypt->verify($password, $user->getPassword())) {
    // Password is verified
}
```

What is the best way to about it ?

Thanks.

Comment: You are right, i think the better approach is to have a PasswordService class

Comment: If you plan to add another methods that will handle the password, this approach makes sense. Otherwise, what's the difference between use of `Bcrypt` class and `PasswordService` class (in case of your 2nd question)?

Comment: You won't separate yourself from framework either way unless you use some `HashingMechanism` interface that is (for now) implemented by `BcryptProxy` class.

Comment: I am building a zend-framework-2 module which is supposed to be reusable and extensible across projects, while Bcrypt may work for me i don't want force it upon users, the point is to allow developers to adopt it as they need but by default use Bcrypt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And maybe you can just create a Password class and move this logic there?
You can either do something like this:

```
class Password
{
    private $password;
    public __construct($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public crypt(Zend_Crypt_Password_PasswordInterface $crypt)
    {
        $this->password = $crypt->create($password);
    }
}
```

or use a [Decorator](http://bfy.tw/465Y).
Both solution gives you a possibility for extending your code.
Instead of `Zend_Crypt_Password_PasswordInterface` you can also use your own [Wrapper](http://bfy.tw/465e). It would be IMHO even better solution.

And then you can set the password for particular user and it does not care whether it was crypted, hashed or whatever:

```
class User
{
    private $password;

    public function changePassword(Password $password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you pointed to the right direction. I ended up implementing a password interface so any extending class must use this interface, this way any password creation or matching algorithm can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I guess first approach is better because its *hide* using of bcrypt within User class.

I dont think that other programmer have to keep in mind that he have to use, for example, `$bcrypt->verify` when working with `User` class.

Comment: I think the rule for a better design is always to assume that there will be a change. although i agree that it is better to hide the inner function, i also think at the same time that there are several creational design patterns that allows us to deal with such things.